# how to remove /n from list results?

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

Hello everyone I'm scraping a table and separating the headers and the body of the table into separate lists but the body data has a lot of '/n' and I'm trying to remove them but I cant seem to get them out.

code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html.parser')
table= soup.find("table")
rows= table.find_all("tr")
table_contents = []
for tr in rows:
    if rows.index(tr)== 0:
        row_cells = [ th.getText().strip() for th in tr.find_all('th') if th.getText().strip() !='']
    else:
        row_cells = ([ tr.find('th').getText() ] if tr.find('th') else [] ) + [ td.getText().strip() for td in tr.find_all('td') if td.getText().strip() != '' ] 
    if len(row_cells) > 1 : 
        table_contents += [ row_cells ]
table_head= table_contents[0]
table_body= table_contents[1]
print (table_head)
print (table_body)
```

Results:

```
table head= ['Student Number', 'Student Name', 'Placement Date']
table body= ['20808456', 'Sandy\n(f) \nGurlow', '01/13/2023']
```

As you can see in the table body results '\n' is in the way and I can figure out how to get rid of it. As I have 100's of samples to pull with the same issue.

Comment: `str.strip` only removes characters from the left or the right of a string. It does not remove characters in the middle of the string. Have you tried `str.replace`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `str.replace()` and list comprehension:

```
[i.replace('\n', '') for i in table_body]
```

Output:

```
['20808456', 'Sandy(f) Gurlow', '01/13/2023']
```

Comment: I attempted to use `table_body= table_contents[1]` `[i.replace('\n', '') for i in table_body]` but when i print the body it still has the \n in there?

Comment: do ```table_body = [i.replace('\n', '') for i in table_body]```  after ```table_body= table_contents[1]```